# View's background disappear in Android

Tags: android, listview, background, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Sometimes when Activity is launched background of view (example ListView) is not visible (but sometimes everything is ok). It does not matters if it is drawable or color and it does not happens always. You can launch the same activity 10 times and issue will happen only once or twice.

Issue happens on ICS (4.0) or later devices, on older version of android everything is ok.

How do we fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your OnCreate method, after setting the background and the adapter.

```
    getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
```